# Error as please use version that support this project

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2008-r2

I need to make the change son rdl files so I had installed Visual studio 2008.
but when I am trying to open the project below issue arises.

> please use version  that support this project

Please review below image
[image]

**How can I open it successfully or how can I identify that which version it supports?**

Comment: Looks like the project was opened in a newer version (hence "upgrade") to that version. try opening it with a newer version of Visual Studio.

Comment: @Harry I had also tried opening in 2010 version but still it is not working

Answer (score 0):

Try opening it in SQL Server Express with Advanced Services.

Here is a good article: https://www.spiria.com/en/blog/web-applications/visual-studio-does-not-recognize-rptproj-files